# Finding number of comparisons

Tags: java, binary-search, bug-tracking

I'm trying to track the number of key comparisons in this binary search code. The comparison result should be around 17 for an array size of `2^16`. Can you explain why I'm getting 33?

```
public class AdvancedBinarySearch {

    int count = 0;

    // Returns location of key, or -1 if not found 
    int AdvancedBinarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
        int m;

        while (r - l > 1) {
            count++;
            m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (arr[m] <= x) {
                l = m;
                count++;
            } else {
                r = m;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (arr[l] == x) {
            count++;
            return l;
        }

        if (arr[r] == x) {
            count++;
            return r;

        } else {
            count++;
            return -1;

        }
    }

    public void setCount(int i) {
        this.count = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example program to run this and reproduce the number?

Comment: You bumped `count` both _before_ and _after_ the comparison in the `while` loop.  So it's no surprise that you're result is about double what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is counting the `if (arr[m] <= x)` comparison twice. if you remove the `count++` from below `l = m` and also from below `r = m`, this will no longer happen.

I have tested this before and after this change with a search for 189 in an array of the integers from 0 to 65535. This array had a size of 2^16 and before the change, 33 comparisons were counted and after the change, 17 comparisons were counted, so I think this change does what you want it to do.